# In a typical list -> details SwiftUI app, what is the best way to create new elements?

Tags: swiftui

In a typical list -> details SwiftUI view, I have basically an `Array` of objects, and for read/edit, I can easily bind these (using `@Binding` on the view) to view and edit the elements in the array.

What about adding new elements?

I would like to re-use my views for editing; but they expect an `@Binding` as I mentioned. How do I transition to this view if I want to allow the user to add a new element to the list?

One option is that I can pre-create an object before loading the view, and then binding the view to the new element. However, this makes "cancel" clunky (now I have to remove from the list). Also, it's not clear how to inject this logic (create a new element) in a `NavigationLink`.

Another option is that I can pass the list to the view and bind a constant empty object, and in the view I can manage adding the new element to the list upon successful creation.

What is the recommended approach to this? I see a lot of tutorials on how to edit and view lists, but not on how to add.

Comment: Actually my code is very similar to the Landmarks tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation). If you can comment on the best approach to extend the tutorial "add a new landmark" I would be able to adapt that strategy to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a backing database. I used Apple's Core Data to add and retrieve stored objects to/from. Here's the guide I used: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-combine-core-data-and-swiftui

Comment: I will do that eventually, but there must be a way to do an in memory update using, for example, the LandMarks app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this that is quite nice.

What I've done is that in the list (say, `LandmarkList`), I added a default `LandMark` element (which represents the new element to add).

```
@Published var newLandMark : Landmark
```

I wrap my view with a new view, which binds against the list:

```
struct NewLandmarkView : LandmarkDetail {
  @Binding var landmarkList : LandmarkList
}
```

This view adds buttons for `save` and `cancel`. Add takes the `newLandmark` and adds it to the list.

I then use the following to show modally (you can navigate to it if you want instead):

```
Button(action: {
    // In the folder list view, we'll add a note to the "notes" folder
    self.showModal = true
}) {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
}.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
    CreateLandmarkView(landmarkList: self.$landmarkList)
}
```

This worked pretty well for me as a pattern.